# Using a Choice Complex Datatype with JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I have the following XML message and I need to deserialize it

```
<xs:complexType name="DataType">
   <xs:choice>
       <xs:element name="Ext_a_Data" type="ExtTest1DataType" />
       <xs:element name="Ext_b_Data" type="ExtTest2DataType" />
       <xs:element name="Ext_c_Data" type="ExtTest3DataType" />
   </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XmlElements` annotation is used to map a choice structure.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html